# ITHIT WebDAV Ajax library with Anonymous authentication

Tags: javascript, ms-office, ithit-webdav-server

We are exploring ITHit WebDAV AJAX Library for one of our requirements to provide ability to edit any file type with in the browser. 
At the moment I downloaded the 1 month free trail to check whether the library meets all our requirements. I created the sample application using the example provided [here](https://www.webdavsystem.com/ajax/programming/open-doc-webpage/opening_ms_office_docs/). I enabled WebDAV in IIS and set the authentication to anonymous. I could access the file and view the contents in it, but when I try to save the file it asks me to sign in and nothing happens once I click the sign in button.
Interestingly, when I enable Windows authentication in the site I could view and save the changes. 
Do I need to have any extra configuration/custom code to support file editing when only anonymous authentication is enabled? Or is it a limitation?

Note – I’m using Office 2016, win 10, IE 11, WebDAV is enabled at the site root level.

Answer (score 0):

Built-in IIS WebDAV does not support anonymous access as far as we know. Your server must have authentication enabled.